# List Workers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Is there a native built-in way to list running Workers in Javascript?
( aside from Web Inspector Threads panel or your own list of references )

Comment: No there is no way, even overwritting the Worker constructor to add a counter wouldn't help since Workers can be created from inside Workers too. Why do you think you need to know that?

Comment: More precise management of worker resources in my app.

Comment: So you'd need access to these Workers anyway, and if you have access to it, you can count these.